# Where's the Removed State on Tasks in VSTS/TFS?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I want to soft delete a **Task** by setting it to the `removed` state but I don't see it there.  This approach works great on user stories/PBI but it doesn't seem to be there for tasks.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task state for Agile template and Scrum template has `Removed` state. And you can find the related workflow in below links:

[Agile workflow states](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow#agile-workflow-states)

[Scrum workflow states](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/scrum-process-workflow#scrum-workflow-states)

**One thing to note:**

You can only change task state to `Removed` when the task state is `New` (for Agile) or `To Do` (for Scrum).

Such as in Scrum template, when a task state is `To Do`, you can find the `Removed` state in drop down list. If the task state is `Done`, there won’t show `Removed` state in drop down list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right!  I thought I tested it on my 'clean' VSTS instance but I guess not.  'They' must have customized the VSTS instance I'm working so I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Note, because of Microsoft changing the UI so frequently, my view might look slightly different from yours. One of these two options should work.

Right click on the desired task and select `Disable selected task(s)`.

[image]

-- OR --

Select the task, expand the `Control Options` section. There is a check box `Enabled` and if you un-check it, the task won't run.

[image: Enable/Disable VSTS Task]

Comment: @spottedmahn was talking about work item states, not about build definition tasks